# html5 datalist question

Tags: html

What does the following sentence mean in layman's terms.

`The contents of the datalist element represent fallback content for legacy user agents, intermixed with option elements that represent the predefined options.`

Answer (score 1):

The datalist element provides the ability to offer suggestions for a field such as a search. Older browsers that don't support the datalist element will display whatever text you embed within the element, so it can degrade gracefully by providing an error message, and newer browsers will utilize the option values.

For example:

```
<datalist id="example">
    Your browser does not support the datalist element.
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: True, though I wouldn't *want* to display such a message.  It's unlikely to do anything to help the user.